# Creating n-ary tree with weights for each branch

Tags: python, tree

In Python, I want to create a n-ary tree with any number of branches where each branch gets a weight. Here is the example:
    Node A has three children B, C, D with weights 100, -200, 250;
    B is leaf node;
    C has two children E, F with weights 150, 200;
    E and F are leaf nodes;
    D has two children G and H with weights -50, 100;
    G and H are leaf nodes;
Can you please show me how to construct this with examples.

> > >
> >     Thank you machine yearning.
> >     Thank you. After looking at your example, I think it forced me to rethink the problem. Instead of assigning weights, I would assign probabality for

each child path. Each child node would acrue the weight if it took that path.
So there pictorically it would look like this, each node having probabality and the weight accrued.

A 0
B 100
C 250
D 150
E
F 200
G -50
H 100

A     B   C     D    E   F   G   H

A  0  .25  .35    .4   0   0   0   0

B  0    0    0    0    0   0   0   0

C  0    0    0    0   .6   .4  0   0

D  0    0    0    0    0   0   .5  .5

E  0    0    0    0    0   0   0   0

F  0    0    0    0    0   0   0   0

I would start with something like this.
class Adjacency:
    def **init**(self, wt):
    self.wt = wt
        self.adj = []

Then I would like to do this:

For root, there would be no weight.
Then as I add a child recursively, I want to add the probabality for the path it took, basically looking backwards towards its parent. Then add the weight to the child that was added. So when the child becomes next parent, I do not add weight, as I alerady added the weight in the previous step. But for a leaf node I have to add the weight.
Also I don't know for sure if multiple paths would lead to a node, but I want to keep that option as you suggested.

I don't understand the code below, can you please explain how it will work to fit the scenario I explained. I am new to Python.

```
def add_node(self):
    for row in self.adj:
        row.append(inf)
    self.adj.append([inf] * (len(self.adj) + 1))

def set_weight(self, i, j, w):
    if i >= j:
        raise ValueError("Don't make a cycle")
    self.adj[i][j] = w
```

Sorry, the formatting got messed up, I hope you understand my posting.

Comment: How about giving each node a weight?

Answer (score 3):

This should be enough to get your started:

```
class TreeNode():
     def __init__(self,initWeight=<default>):
        self.children = List()
        self.weight = initWeight

    def addChild(self, weight):
        self.children.append(TreeNode(weight))
```

You just need a list of children and a weight field. You can get fancier from there. In your main program:

```
from treefile import TreeNode

if  __name__ == "__main__":
    root = TreeNode(5)
    root.addChild(100)
```

Would make

A(weight=5)
   |
B(weight=100)

You could give A as many children as you want and get references to the children by looking at the child list.

Answer (score 1):

I don'T know what you really want. And you didn't provide any code to comment on. So it's up to you to elaborate. Meanwhile i could give an example of a general "Node" class. But there sure are better examples out there on the net.

```
class Node(object):
   def __init__(self):
      self.children = []
      self.weight = 0

   def add_branch(self, node):
      self.children.append(node)

   def is_branch(self):
       return len(self.children) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I guess you will want to use algorithms with those trees, I would recomend you to use the networkx package.

Comment: I want to create web page with a tree and for each of the nodes I want to be able to assign values and edit. Can I do this with the networkx pkg?

Comment: Sure! Read the excellent tutorial at http://networkx.lanl.gov/tutorial/tutorial.html

Comment: If you find my answer useful, please vote for it... I just started using stackoverflow and I am short of reputation ;)

Answer (score 0):

I know you said in your question you were working with trees; however since your question was fairly contextless, I'm not totally convinced you know what you want.

Giving nodes a weight makes some sense in the context of this problem, except for at the root; however it totally breaks when you try to generalize the model to work with acyclic digraphs. You might just have a second list in your node that stores the weight of each child.

You can also model an acyclic digraph with no loops as a triangular matrix (a 2-d list of weights which satisfies the property that for all indices `i` in the outer list, all weights of indices `j <= i` are infinite).

Here's what your original example yields by this model (I've switched the letters to numbers corresponding to indexes like A->0, B->1 :

```
    A     B     C     D     E     F     G     H
A  inf   100  -200   250   inf   inf   inf   inf
B  inf   inf   inf   inf   inf   inf   inf   inf
C  inf   inf   inf   inf   150   200   inf   inf
D  inf   inf   inf   inf   inf   inf   -50   100
E  inf   inf   inf   inf   inf   inf   inf   inf   
F  inf   inf   inf   inf   inf   inf   inf   inf
```

In the code this would be as simple as creating an adjacency matrix:

```
class Adjacency:
    def __init__(self):
        self.adj = []

    def add_node(self):
        for row in self.adj:
            row.append(inf)
        self.adj.append([inf] * (len(self.adj) + 1))

    def set_weight(self, i, j, w):
        if i >= j:
            raise ValueError("Don't make a cycle")
        self.adj[i][j] = w
```

Now it's up to your context to determine what value you use for infinity, etc.

Just a different approach, not necessarily better, and definitely has its drawbacks. It does have the advantage that if you're looking to have multiple paths to a node, a tree won't cut it.

Comment: Thank you. I am rephrasing my question, can you pl. respond.

Comment: I don't understand how add_node works, can you pl. explain? Also I rephrased my question in view of your response, can you give suggestions?